# How to show Selected value from dropdown inside table in dot net core mvc with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
'''
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GridData", "PeriodOpenclose")/',
            dataType: "json",
              success: function (response) {
                  debugger
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(response.data, function (i, List) {
                        var newRow = $("<tr>");
                        var cols = "";
cols += '<td> <select id="dropdowntype"  class="form-control"><option value="1">Open </option> <option value="2">Close </option></select ></td > ';
                        $("#dropdowntype").val($("#dropdowntype option:selected").val(List.periodstatus));
'''
```

I added this  inside table i have added select tag and Manually option is added. i am selecting value 2 in List.periodstatus,i am unable to display selected value in dropdown.

Comment: I'm confused by the code, When do you add `cols` to your html? because right before you call `$("#dropdowntype")` you do `cols += '<td> ` but never uses `cols`

Comment: Also I'm not sure what you are trying to do here `$("#dropdowntype").val($("#dropdowntype option:selected").val(List.periodstatus));`

Comment: ignore $("#dropdowntype").val($("#dropdowntype option:selected").val(List.periodstatus)); this just i will append cols into table but main issue is that how suppose to set selected value in this dropdown ,i want to set List.periodstatus to this dropdown as value

Comment: You never show us how you append `cols `to the html, if you dont append it then you cant use `$("#dropdowntype")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set selected option of `<select></select>` which id is dropdowntype,you only need to change cols,and then add cols to html.

```
var cols = "";

            cols += '<select id="dropdowntype"  class="form-control">';
            for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
                if (j == List.periodstatus) {
                    cols += '<option value="' + j + '" selected>Open </option>';
                } else {
                    cols += '<option value="' + j + '">Open </option>';
                }
            }
            cols += '</select >';
```

After using the code,`selected` will added to the `option` which value is `List.periodstatus` in `cols`.